# Powershell to replacing AD proxyAddresses with new domain

Tags: powershell

I have smtp address beginning with nby keyword like below.

I will remove nby24048@olddomain.com and nby44048@olddomain.com and add nby24048@domainA.com and nby44048@domainA.com. So I will replace those with new domain.

for example :

```
sAMAccountName,ProxyAddresses
user01,SMTP:user01@domainA.com;smtp:user01@domainA.com;smtp:nby24048@olddomain.com
user02,SMTP:user02@domainA.com;smtp:user02@domainA.com;smtp:nby44048@olddomain.com
....
so on
```

Here is my script so far:

```
$Users = import-csv "c:\temp\users.csv"

Foreach ($User in $Users)

            {
            $Samaccountname = $User.samaccountname
            
           
            Set-ADUser $samaccountname -Remove @{proxyAddresses=$SMTP}
            Set-ADUser $samaccountname -Add @{proxyAddresses=$SMTP}
            }
```

Comment: Just to make this a bit clearer: you want to replace all addresses starting with `nby` and ending with `@olddomain.com` to become `nbySomething@domainA.com`, or to become `samaccountname@domainA.com` ?

Comment: yes like you said , "I want to replace all addresses starting with nby and ending with @olddomain.com to become nbySomething@domainA.com"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, to replace those addresses you can do like below:

```
$Users = Import-Csv -Path "c:\temp\users.csv"
foreach ($user in $Users) {
    $sam = $user.samaccountname
    $adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$sam'" -Properties ProxyAddresses
    if ($adUser) {
        $proxies = $adUser.ProxyAddresses | ForEach-Object {
            $_ -replace '^(smtp:nby.+)@olddomain\.com$', '$1@domainA.com'
        } | Sort-Object -Unique

        # $proxies needs to be a strongly typed string array, so cast to [string[]]
        $adUser | Set-ADUser -Replace @{proxyAddresses = [string[]]$proxies}
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Could not find user '$sam'.."
    }
}
```